# How do I weave the backpack shoulder straps when there are two strap adjusters?

Tags: backpacks

I've attached a picture, I got this used backpack (Dana Design Arcflex Astraplane) and I'm trying to figure out the straps on this thing. I noticed there are two strap adjusters on the top.. are they redundant and I just use one? Or there's something I'm missing?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok, I think I figured it out, the guy before me did a weird thing so it confused me. But I think one is for the shoulder strap and the other for the lid of the bag. I included a pic, please let me know if someone thinks it goes differently. (The picture is looking down from the top)[image]

Comment: That seems most likely, especially if there's no where else to attach the lid.

Comment: That's definitely it.

Answer (score 3):

You would only want to use one of them at a time. With that said there are a couple of possibilities here,

- There is another strap that you have missed that goes to the second point (this is the most likely option)
- There was a strap that used to go there but was cut off.

I would double check the backpack for other straps.